# Disable certificate check for Wappalyzer

Tags: ssl, certificate, verification

I am running the docker cli for Wappalyzer from a RHEL box. We have a number of sites we scan by IP address where the certificate verification prevents Wappalyzer from returning results. Is there a way to disable the certificate check for Wappalyzer or RHEL like you can for wget with --no-check-certificate?

Answer (score 0):

The Github repo now includes a commit, strictSSL: false, to resolve the issue.

https://github.com/AliasIO/Wappalyzer/commit/09ebc4aa486b5151ab05344e7611006a877408c2